# Pressing enter key on Ordered/Unordered list adds <br> after each <li> element

Tags: javascript, css, list, contenteditable

Am working with contentEditable element that has some text formatting associated with it. But with the use of ordered or unordered list items, chrome and firefox adds `<br>` everytime I press enter after the first `<li>`. 
The generated html text looks something like the following:

```
Hello
    <ul>
      <li>World<br></li>
      <li>the great<br></li>
      <li> <br></li>
    </ul>
```

How can I remove the off-the-grid `<br>` tags being added to each li tag? Is it possible to do it using CSS or just using javascript?

Comment: How are you adding the div's contents to the list? Naively, I'd simply say don't add the br elements - rather than try to remove them after the fact.

Comment: I am using a contentEditable div that has text formatting enabled. So, when I write on the editor and start to use unordered-list for example the caret navigates below the li because of the added <br>. I want to somehow remove the <br> element.

Comment: Cool, that answers the (unasked) question of what are you using to receive the text input. What I was (am) trying to find out is how you go from (a) the contents of the source element (a content editable div, with text formatting enabled) to (b) the html list. Which/what operation/s occur to turn the users' typing into `<li>` elements?

Comment: Am not sure if this helps but I can write plain text in the editor but I am getting the HTML format by calling some javascript functions like,   alert($("#contenteditor").html()); Its by checking the output of this that I have come to understand a <br> is being added after each <li>

Comment: This example (http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) shows a `<section>` tag that has content-editable='true'. It has a heading, a paragraph and an ordered list. You can add items to the list or edit the other two. It doesn't appear to add `<br>` elements to the mark-up. Does this help you?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS :

```
ul li br {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action of pressing enter will not generate `<br>`, see http://jsfiddle.net/fudesign2008/2As6J/.
Is there any bug in js code of your project.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I had a bug in my code and after fixing that it is working now. No more <br> getting added for the ordered/unordered lists.